# What does an example of a Swift header file look like?

Tags: swift

I am at a loss and I give up - what does a header file look like in swift? How can I have a header with a variable, say *'exampleHeaderStr:String = "how do I...?"'*  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as header files in swift. You declare all variables in the implementation, marking them as private or internal or public. See the swift intro guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: I know, what you're saying is true. I'm just sick of always having my Globals.swift file, a personal choice of mine made a long time ago... answer glumly accepted ;)